# Discrete analogue of Green's theorem

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, soft-question

Following formula concerning [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) is in a way a discrete analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\sum_{n=a}^b \Delta f(n) = f(b+1) - f(a) $$

We can think about the [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) as a two-dimensional generalization of fundamental theorem of calculus, so I'm interested is there a discrete analogue of Green's theorem?

Comment: See http://people.csail.mit.edu/tieu/notebook/imageproc/tang82.pdf, http://people.csail.mit.edu/tieu/notebook/imageproc/brlek.pdf...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely about summation: in a partition of a plane region $R$, we have the following for any function $G$ defined on the edges of the partition:
$$\sum_{\partial R} G=\sum_{R} \Delta G$$
($\Delta G$ is defined on the faces of the partition).

Comment: I can’t find any literature on this, do you have any links or references. I would like to work out a concrete example.

Comment: @ frogeyedpeas It's in the book I am writing, Calculus Illustrated. Here is a link to the relevant section: http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Vector_fields#The_Fundamental_Theorem_of_Discrete_Calculus_of_degree_.242.24 . If you want to see where this comes from, take a look at my last book Topology Illustrated, Chapter 6, http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Topology_Illustrated .